# Firestore ordering a limits

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order the top bars in my database by their "Litness" or "Rating". I am also trying to limit the number of bars returned to three.

I've tried using .orderBy('Litness', Query.Direction.DESCENDING) but it always returns with:

> Variable not found: Query

```
firebase.firestore().collection('bars')
    .where('litness', '>', '0.5').orderBy('Litness', desc).limit(3)
    .get().then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc);
   })
})
```

I expect the return to order my bars by the highest three that are rated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is tagged with Android, but the code you're showing is for JavaScript.  That needs to be changed.

Once you get that straightened out, if you want to use the [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) class, you will need to import it into your code.  Android Studio probably has some quick fix to help you with this, but somehow you're going to have to use this along with the other imports:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.Query;
```